# Format number in US Phone number format while typing in the Editor

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, string-formatting

Have a phone number textbox, it has to be formatted like US phone number format on the go.

If a single character typed, let say 9

In this case it should be displayed as 9

Next 8 is typed and it should be displayed as 98

Next 9 is typed and it should be displayed as 989-

Next 1 is typed and it should be displayed as 989-1

Like wise it should be format the 10 digits.

Format : `###-###-####`

I got some help but it was used to format after complete typing the 10 digits. Used Regex format and ToString() formatting.

```
public static string formatPhoneNumber(string phoneNum, string phoneFormat)
    {
        //phoneNum = "        12";
        if (phoneFormat == "")
        {
            // If phone format is empty, code will use default format (###) ###-####
            phoneFormat = "###-###-####";
        }

        // First, remove everything except of numbers
        Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"[^\d]");
        phoneNum = regexObj.Replace(phoneNum, "");

        // Second, format numbers to phone string 
        if (phoneNum.Length > 0)
        {

            phoneNum = Convert.ToInt64(phoneNum).ToString(phoneFormat);
        }

        return phoneNum;
    }
```

Using the text changed event and calling this method to format the text every text change.

Comment: Could we have some code of what you've tried so far? Also, we don't even know if you're writing a C# console application, Android Xamarin App, etc.

Comment: Using Xamarin forms with C# - Added the receptive tags.

Comment: Are you using a Text editor box? If so, based on [this page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor/#TextChanged) you can handle the text changed event, and add your "-" based on the `Count` of characters entered in real time.

Comment: Does it work with calling the function every time text changes? If it takes long, you can write different code to check step by step, e.g. counting the length of `e.OldTextValue;`, comparing it to `e.NewTextValue;`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private string PhoneNumberFormatter(string value)
    {
        value = new Regex(@"\D").Replace(value, string.Empty);

        if (value.Length > 3 & value.Length < 7)
        {
            value = string.Format("{0}-{1}", value.Substring(0, 3), value.Substring(3, value.Length - 3));
            return value;
        }
        if (value.Length > 6 & value.Length < 11)
        {
            value = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", value.Substring(0, 3), value.Substring(3, 3), value.Substring(6));
            return value;
        }
        if (value.Length > 10)
        {
            value = value.Remove(value.Length - 1, 1);
            value = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", value.Substring(0, 3), value.Substring(3, 3), value.Substring(6));
            return value;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

With the above method, my requirement is fulfilled but if any optimized way is there please let me know.